# Python: plot different kinds of colors

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I wan t to plot 8 lines in a one figure with different color, and labels. however, there are two problems:
1) I found some lines almost the same color, I want to differet color for lines.
2) label is in the middle, I want to put on the upper right, and make the size smaller

My code is following:

```
    import matplotlib.cm as cm

    colors = iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(lst_year))))
    for i in range(len(lst_year)):
         plt.plot(lst_month, lst_all[i], label='201{i} year'.format(i=i), color=next(colors))
    plt.legend(loc='best')
```

and my figure is following:

[image: figure]

Comment: Those are two completely unrelated problems. If you have two questions, ask two questions. However you will find a lot of answers for both problems, so you should include in how far they do not help you.

Comment: The legend location is determined by the `loc` parameter. See e.g. [How to put legend out of plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132)